# UITextField border disappear when show HUD

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I've a strange behavior.
I set the border on `UITextField`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.usernameTextField.layer.borderColor    = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
    self.usernameTextField.layer.borderWidth    = 1.0f;
}
```

and while performing login I show a `MDProgressHud` attached on window (so automatically disable all buttons and gesture on the view below).

```
AppDelegate * app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];            
self.hud          = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:app.window];            
[app.window addSubview:self.hud];
```

So, when the hud is shown the border disappears...

Idea about the cause ?

Comment: Where do you set the border? How do you display the progress HUD?

Comment: Attach a KVO observer to the text field's layer's `borderColor` property and find out where and when it changes, if it changes at all.

Comment: I've no idea how to make... please write an answer and if works I can accept it

Comment: That's not the way things work here. You're expected to know basic programming patterns of the platform you're working on. Please find that out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I just had an issue with my border colour changing. KVO as suggested by @duci9y was very useful for working out what went wrong:

```
[textField addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"layer.borderColor" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) context:nil];
```

Add the observer:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if([keyPath isEqual:@"layer.borderColor"]) {
        NSLog(@"Border colour changed");
    }
}
```

I put a breakpoint on the NSLog and found the issue.